# Angular form data binding not binding data

Tags: html, angular, forms

I know I am doing something incredibly stupid. I have two forms in my html page. One for posting a comment and one for search. The comment posting one works properly, but the search one does not bind data properly. It goes to its clickHandler, but I cannot get the data to bind.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="searchbar-container">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <form class="form mb-3" (ngSubmit)="onSearchSubmit(searchForm)" #searchForm="ngForm">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" [(ngModel)]="searchString">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit"  [disabled]="!searchForm.valid">Search</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the component. I am just posting the click handler method. searchString is a string available to the whole class

```
searchString : any = "";

onSearchSubmit(form: NgForm) {
  console.log("came to Search onSubmit");
  console.log(this.searchString)
  
  
}
```

printing the searchString prints an empty string. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Import `FormsModule` from `@angular/forms`, set the property as `string` (if you are using typescript, do not use `any` type)

If you are using ngModel inside a form tag, set name attribute on input tag `NG01352`

Working example:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule],
  template: `
    <form (submit)="submit()">
      <input type="text" name="search" [(ngModel)]="searchString" />
      <br/>
      <p>Text: {{searchString}}</p>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  `,
})
export class App {
  searchString: string = '';

  submit(): void {
    console.log(this.searchString);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pci4um?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Findex.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer... however since I already have a working form in my html page (this question is about adding a second form), I do have the necessary imports. The data type of the searchString was String originally as well, but that did not help either.  I would like to try the input tag name thing. So the <input> tag should have name NG01352?